Projects you made
Which projects you made that get you to expert level in solidity? I'm trying to be a smart contract dev. with solidity and wanna see which ones you made so I could benefit from it.

I’ve made various projects by following the amazing tutorials of Patrick Collins.
Patrick, being a Web3 OG, has even started Cyfrin Updraft with an initiative to enable Web3 developers with the skills that they need to become superb smart contract developers and security researchers, and that too completely free.
On Cyfrin Updraft, there are various top-notch courses containing in-depth lessons.
Among those courses, I’ve completed:

Blockchain Basics

Solidity 101: containing in-depth    lessons on fundamentals of Solidity and    covering projects like SimpleStorage,
StorageFactory and FundMe using Remix IDE.

Foundry 101: containing in-depth lessons on fundamentals of Foundry and covering projects including all the ones covered in Solidity 101 using Foundry (including writing scripts, tests and emphasizing the usage of best practices while writing smart contracts), plus some advanced projects like Smart Contract Lottery in which various libraries and utilities are being used including Chainlink VRF, Chainlink Automation, etc.


I’ve almost completed Foundry 101, after that I would go for Advanced Foundry and so on.
So, if you want to become an expert in Solidity and not just write smart contracts but follow all the best practices, whether from a "security" point of view or "contributing to various big open-source projects" point of view, I highly recommend you try out those courses. No matter what level you're currently at, you'll end up becoming a far better version of yourself. I'm speaking from personal experience, as Patrick's way of teaching is just out of this world.
P.S., I’m just one of the 100,000+ students who have enrolled in the courses, not associated with Cyfrin Updraft by any means. But yeah, I’m a huge fan of Patrick though.

thx bro will look into it. I heard about Cyfrin Updraft and it wasnt available couple of months ago thx anyway have a good one.

You're welcome @seojunchian. It became open for everyone since Feb 22, 2024, as they've announced in this tweet.
